# Finding the components of B in the Electromagnetic field tensor

Tags: electromagnetism, magnetic-fields, field-theory, conventions, notation

I have a bit of confusion about how magnetic field components are written in function of the field tensor.

I have the metric $(-,+,+,+)$ so my field tensor is this

$$
F^{\mu \nu} \, = \,\left(\begin{matrix}0 & E_1 & E_{2} & E_{3} \\ -E_{1} & 0 & B^{3} & -B^{2} \\ -E_2 & -B^{3} & 0 & B^1 \\ -E_3 & B^{2} & -B^{1} & 0\end{matrix}\right)\tag{3}
$$

I normalize the Levi-Civita symbol in this way: $\epsilon^{123}=1$

In many textbooks and in the instructor's notes the components of B are defined like that:

$$B^k = \frac{1}{2} \epsilon^{ijk} F^{ij}$$

$i,j,k$ run from $1$ to $3$.

So, for example, to find $B^3$, which is clearly $F^{12}$, I set $k=3$ and sum over the permutation of the Levi-Civita symbol obtaining something like that

$$\frac{1}{2}( \epsilon^{123} F^{12} + \epsilon^{213} F^{21}) = \frac{1}{2}( F^{12} - F^{21}) = F^{12} = B^3$$

But I don't really know why I'm summing, or if there's something that tells me to sum over the permutations of $i$ and $j$, I'm summing just cause in this way I obtain the right result. But I think it would be simpler to write

$$ B^k=\epsilon^{ijk} F^{ij} $$

In this way no summation is required, you simply compute the value of $\epsilon^{ijk}$.

For example, $k=3$, $i$ and $j$ are now free so I write $\epsilon^{ijk}$ giving a value to $i$ and the other to $j$, picking the simpler choice I have $B^3= \epsilon^{123} F^{12}= 1 F^{12}$.  The other choice is $B^3= \epsilon^{213} F^{21}= -F^{21}= F^{12}$

So my questions are:

why that way of writing $B^k$ and not the other simpler one?

Why summing over permutation? I mean what tells me that I have to sum over the permutations and not just pick a value for $i$ and $j$ and compute the value of the Levi-Civita tensor?

Comment: The only difference between the first and the second formula is that you omitted the 1/2 in the second one, I'm not sure why you think that one is better or what you mean by "no summation is required" - what do you mean by "calculat[ing] the value of $\epsilon^{ijk}$"?

Comment: @ACuriousMind I edited the question, I hope it's clearer now. Sorry for the "calculating" I just translated from my first language and that was wrong

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That's not how index notation works. You say that in
$$ B^k = \epsilon^{ijk}F^{ij}\tag{1}$$
you are "free to choose" the $i$ and $j$, but then you only make the two choices (1,2) and (2,1) for which that gives the correct results. What about $i=1,j=3$, or $i=2,j=2$? You chose those specific $i$s and $j$s because you *knew what result you wanted*, not because it's somehow a choice dictated by the notation (1).

To avoid such ambiguous choices, *all indices in index notation must occur either on both sides of the equation or be summed over*. The general convention is to sum over repeated indices, although in your relativistic setting the index position is actually relevant and the equation should be written
$$ B^k = \epsilon^{ijk} F_{ij}. \tag{2}$$
Here you are now summing over *all* possible values for $i$ and $j$, not only over their permutations - but those indices $ijk$ which are not permutations of $123$ simply yield zero because the Levi-Civita symbol is zero for those indices.

Comment: Yes you're right I didn't notice the other possibilities and excluded them. Thanks for your clear and precise answer. So If I encounter something like $1/2 \, \epsilon^{ijk}F^{ij}$, if I want to write it using B explicitly I should lower 2 indices first and then summing? Another thing, I'm not sure, but maybe in your answer in $(2)$, shouldn't it be $F_{ij}$